# Getting the HINSTANCE from HWND

Tags: winapi, hwnd, hinstance

GetWindowLong (GetTopWindow(NULL),GWL_HINSTANCE) returns 0 ...
(Also tried with GetWindowLongPtr) 
Does anyone have an idea why is that?

Also how do you convert LONG to HINSTANCE?

- GetTopWindow(NULL) does not return null

EDIT: The check is for a keylogger that is injected inside the application I want to log from. 
Using GetModuleHandle(0) I get the HINSTANCE of my injected app and if I could have the top window's HINSTANCE I could check to see if the input I get is for my application or not.

Comment: Please explain what you intend to use the HINSTANCE for. The top window may not belong to your process, so its instance handle is useless to you.

Comment: GetTopWindow() probably returned NULL.  You'll have to have a child window for it to return a non-NULL value.  Convert by casting.

Comment: The HINSTANCE is not globally unique. Different processes can have the same HINSTANCE. You need to use some other method of detecting which windows you are interested in.